# JAXB multiple xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have two XSD that I generated through JAXB's xjc command.

http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1.xsd
and
http://www.mmtech.ru/adlcp_v1p3.xsd

I am trying to use the Item object from the first xsd like

`ItemType item = factory.createItemType();

DataType dataType = factory.createDataType();

MapType mapType = factory.createMapType();

dataType.getMap().add(mapType);

item.getAny().add(dataType);`

Note that DataType and MapType are both from the two XSD.

I can generate the xml file expect for one problem, it is giving the error

**Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "packagename.DataType" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation**

So I tried adding the @XmlRootElement to the DataType class and instead of it creating ns2:dataType, it creates the XML below.

```
        <item>
            <dataType>
                <ns2:map targetID="targetid" writeSharedData="false"/>
            </dataType>
        </item>
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Did you run xjc one time with both schemas or one time for each schema file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer my own question.

We should convert the DataType class to a JAXBElement.

```
JAXBElement dataTypeElement = factory.createData(dataType);
item.getAny().add(dataTypeElement);
```